# How to get all items in a column using QList<QStandardItem *>?

Tags: c++, qt, csv, qstandarditemmodel

I need to plot graph from a csv file. I used QList for this. I need to get all items in a specific column such as items in column 4. That's my method to parse csv file and write into a table. I need a method to get the every 4th element of a row.

```
        csvModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);
        csvModel->setColumnCount(17);
        csvModel->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "TEAM ID" << "MISSION TIME" << "PACKET COUNT" << "ALTITUDE" <<"PRESSURE" <<"TEMPERATURE" <<"VOLTAGE" <<"GPS TIME" <<"GPS LATITUDE" <<"GPS LONGITUDE" <<"GPS ALTITUDE" <<"GPS SATS" <<"PITCH" <<"ROLL" <<"BLADE SPIN RATE" <<"SOFTWARE STATE" <<"BONUS DIRECTION");
        ui->csvTableView->setModel(csvModel);

        // Open the file from the resources. Instead of the file
        // Need to specify the path to your desired file
        QFile file("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/test.csv");

        if ( !file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text) ) {
            qDebug() << "File not exists";
        }

        else {
            // Create a thread to retrieve data from a file
            QTextStream in(&file);
            //Reads the data up to the end of file
            while (!in.atEnd())
            {

                QString line = in.readLine();
                // Adding to the model in line with the elements
                QList<QStandardItem *> standardItemsList;
                // consider that the line separated by semicolons into columns
                for (QString item : line.split(",")) {
                    standardItemsList.append(new QStandardItem(item));
                }
                csvModel->insertRow(csvModel->rowCount(), standardItemsList);
            }
            file.close();
        }
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left. You may need to use a browser, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get them like this.

```
QList<QStandardItem*> column;
for (auto row = 0; row < csvModel->rowCount(); row++) {
    column << csvModel->data(csvModel->index(row, 3)).value<QStandardItem*>();
}
```

Otherwise if you want to completely remove the column from the model and get all those items you can use [QStandardItemModel::takeColumn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#takeColumn), remember after calling this that you must manage those pointers since the `QStandardItemModel` releases ownership.

Then if you want to access each element data you could do so.

```
for (int i=0; i<column.size (); i++) {
    series->append(i, column.at(i).data().toInt());
}
```

To be more efficient you can do all this in a single loop.

```
QList<int> series;
for (auto row = 0; row < csvModel->rowCount(); row++) {
    auto item = csvModel->data(csvModel->index(row, 3)).value<QStandardItem*>();
    series << item.data().toInt();
}
```

Comment: You said it was working earlier, what kind of errors are you getting?